# Model modification in Pytorch

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

I want to change weights in a certain kernels in a my saved CNN model. How can I change the values in specific kernels and save to a new model?

Answer (score 1):

You can `torch.load` the weights you saved. You should get a `state_dict` dictionary in which the weights are stored. Use the `state_dict` keys to locate the weights you wish to change, modify them and then `torch.save` the modified `state_dict` (better use different filename ;).